# How to create a filmstrip shape

Tags: html, css, mask

I am trying to achieve an old filmstrip shape (see image).
I would like to be flexible in the amount of images, so I thought the best solution is to do only something with the right side, so the length of the filmstrip doesn't matter.

What is a good way to achieve this?

So the right part is always snapping to the right side of the filmstrip. I can make to parts, where the left part containing the image, and the right part the lower part. But then I don't have the round corners and also what I want is the border that follows the shape, because it will help the filmstrip to separate from the background.

[image]

Comment: How do you want it to look if there are only three images, say?

Comment: @BrettDonald I updated the question with a new image and some additional information when there are for example only 3 images.

Comment: Could you show us your current code?

Comment: Please read [ask] and how to write a [mcve], and then edit to provide all relevant details.

Answer (score 1):

There's a few approaches to this, but one would be to build the shape out of its composite pieces rather than trying to impose the full shape on it afterward. This way, you can add and remove items freely to the container and it will keep that same outer shape since it's only being dictated by the CSS applied to the last item.

You can apply a corner-cut styling to the last item in that sequence, and then follow it up with a smaller partially rounded rectangle to the right. This gets you part of the way there, it'd need some tweaking to look exactly the way that you want.

```css
.filmStrip {
  display: flex;
  border-radius: 4px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.filmStrip__items {
  display: flex;
}
.filmStrip__item {
  background: black;
  width: 150px;
}
.filmStrip__item img {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  transform: scale(0.9);
}

.filmStrip__items > .filmStrip__item:last-of-type,
.filmStrip__items > .filmStrip__item:last-child > img
{
    --corner: 20%;
   clip-path: polygon(
    /* top edge */
    0% 0%, /* left top */
    calc(100% - var(--corner)) 0%, /* right top */
    /* right edge */
    100% var(--corner),              /* right top */
    100% 100%, /* right bottom */
    /* bottom edge*/
    100% 100%, /* right bottom */
    0 100%, /* left bottom*/
    /* left edge */
    0% 100%, /* left bottom */
    0% 0% /* left top */
  );

}

.filmStrip__after {
  display: block;
  width: 100px;
  height: 120px;
  background: black;
  border-radius: 0 4px 4px 0;
  margin-top: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div class="filmStrip">
  <div class="filmStrip__items">
    <div class="filmStrip__item"><img src="https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple1/v4/c8/2d/ef/c82def60-ad06-fe32-8361-4b33d50f8875/source/256x256bb.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="filmStrip__item"><img src="https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple1/v4/c8/2d/ef/c82def60-ad06-fe32-8361-4b33d50f8875/source/256x256bb.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="filmStrip__item"><img src="https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple1/v4/c8/2d/ef/c82def60-ad06-fe32-8361-4b33d50f8875/source/256x256bb.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="filmStrip__item"><img src="https://is3-ssl.mzstatic.com/image/thumb/Purple1/v4/c8/2d/ef/c82def60-ad06-fe32-8361-4b33d50f8875/source/256x256bb.jpg" /></div>
  </div>
  <div class="filmStrip__after"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that you're not answering any specific question. The OP only posted a set of requirements and provided zero work. Please don't answer off-topic questions (specifically, Stack Overflow isn't for posting requirements and having others provide custom solutions)

Comment: While I respect your interpretation of the situation, I did answer a specific question - how to dynamically generate a given shape. If this was a cooking forum and someone asked a question about how to bake a cake that tapers in shape toward the top because they don't know how to approach it, my suggestion would be to bake individual layers of different sizes instead of making a single tall cake in a springform pan and shaving it down afterward. It's a question of approach, with a code sample for clarity

Comment: Please see: [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This isn't a cooking show. This is Stack Overflow, with specific guidelines about how to ask a question. The OP did not ask a specific question - they asked "how can I do this?"

Comment: I didn't say it was a cooking show, I was making a point that a question can be about general approach. If you don't like the question, don't answer it - we're all here to help within our own specialties, and figuring out how to visually represent something through code can be vague and confusing to even know where to start. One of the linked questions on your profile is a 2 paragraph response to a one line question that had no references included and should have been solved by OP with a google search, but I'm not over there bothering you about that.